# Adding a select and joins to already existant complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

Herro friends,
I have a query that was made some time ago by someone else.
I need to add Alarmtzu to the select, and two extra joins. (see the 2nd sql underneath)
Since the query is so complex i'm having trouble finding the right way to fit this in the SQL syntax.

I also have no db schedule available since this is an very old database.

```
SELECT r.refnam, 
       t.tstring,
       rc.cnt namecounter
FROM refdev r
INNER JOIN (SELECT refnam, 
                   COUNT(*) cnt
              FROM refdev rc
          GROUP BY refnam
           ) rc 
        ON rc.refnam = r.refnam
LEFT OUTER JOIN texte t
             ON r.sigtnr = t.textnr
WHERE rc.cnt = 3
ORDER BY r.refnam
```

With

```
SELECT d.alarmzu
FROM devtzu d, OUTER refdev_DEF RD
WHERE D.zustnr = R.zustnr
AND D.dvtypnr = RD.dvtypnr AND R.refnam = RD.refnam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it is correct as their is no database schema. But the way i am viewing the tables, it could be the solution. Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
SELECT r.refnam, 
       t.tstring,
       rc.cnt namecounter,
       d.alarmzu
FROM refdev r
INNER JOIN (SELECT refnam, 
                   COUNT(*) cnt
              FROM refdev rc
          GROUP BY refnam
           ) rc 
        ON rc.refnam = r.refnam
LEFT OUTER JOIN texte t
             ON r.sigtnr = t.textnr
JOIN devtzu d ON d.zustnr = r.zustnr
LEFT OUTER JOIN refdev_DEF RD ON d.dvtypnr = RD.dvtypnr
WHERE r.refnam = RD.refnam
AND rc.cnt = 3
ORDER BY r.refnam
```

Comment: Seems great but 
ERROR: A syntax error has occurred.
Error Code: -201

Comment: Uh, that `WHERE` clause will turn that `LEFT JOIN` into a regular `INNER JOIN`.  Which should it be?